# Store child data in single column

Tags: sqlite, parent-child, hierarchical-data

I have the following tables:

```
 CREATE TABLE titles (
     id INTEGER,
     title VARCHAR(255)
   );
   INSERT INTO titles (id, title) VALUES (1, "Mars Attacks!");
   INSERT INTO titles (id, title) VALUES (2, "Da Vinci Code");

   CREATE TABLE GenreName (
     id INTEGER,
     name VARCHAR(255)
   );

   INSERT INTO GenreName (id, name) VALUES (1, "Action");
   INSERT INTO GenreName (id, name) VALUES (2, "Adventure");
   INSERT INTO GenreName (id, name) VALUES (3, "Comedy");
   INSERT INTO GenreName (id, name) VALUES (4, "Science-Fiction");
   INSERT INTO GenreName (id, name) VALUES (5, "Thriller");

   CREATE TABLE Genre (
     title INTEGER,
     genre INTEGER
   );
   INSERT INTO Genre (title, genre) VALUES (1, 1);
   INSERT INTO Genre (title, genre) VALUES (1, 3);
   INSERT INTO Genre (title, genre) VALUES (1, 4);
   INSERT INTO Genre (title, genre) VALUES (2, 1);
   INSERT INTO Genre (title, genre) VALUES (2, 5);
```

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the data as

```
Id            Title                  Genre
1             Mars Attacks!          Action, Comedy, Science-Fiction
2             Da Vinci Code          Action, Thriller
```

I'm stuck with the recursive way of selecting the data.

I have a [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3v1ukXT4dRX1QtJmfxzHy/14)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select t.id, t.title, group_concat(gn.name) from genere g join titles t on t.id = g.title join genrename gn on gn.id = g.genre group by t.id, t.title

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL OUTER JOINS

`select titles.id, name, title from titles left outer join genre on titles.id = genre.title left outer join genrename on genre.genre = genrename.id;`